# PHP syntax advise

Tags: php, format

I have the following code:

```
$feed->item([
    'title' => $post->title,
    'description|cdata' => $feedy . $post->description,
    'link' => URL::to($post->slug),
    'pubDate' => $pubDate,
    'guid' => $post->title,
    'media:text' => $post->title,
    'dc:creator' => 'Μιχάλης Γεωργίου'
]);
```

I want to integrate this code, which is an example of the code's documentation, but Im not sure how to do it:

```
$item['enclosure'] = [
    'url'=> $image_url,
    'type' => mime_content_type($image_path),
    'length' => filesize($image_path)
];
$feed->item($item);
```

I've tried the following but it didnt work:

```
$feed->item([   
    'title' => $post->title,
    'description|cdata' => $feedy . $post->description,
    'link' => URL::to($post->slug),
    'pubDate' => $pubDate,
    'guid' => $post->title,
    'media:text' => $post->title,
    'dc:creator' => 'Μιχάλης Γεωργίου'
],               

$item['enclosure'] = [
    'url'=> $image_url,
    'type' => mime_content_type($image_path),
    'length' => filesize($image_path)
]);

$feed->item($item);
```

Please advise if this is the correct syntax structure, since Im receiving error regarding the syntax:

`SimpleXMLElement::addChild() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: I think your error is not in this code. see `addChild()` method attributes.

Comment: Are you sure you can have an item of `$item` as an array? Maybe instead of `$item['enclosure'] = [ ... ]` you should have `$item = [ ... ]` . What an example of the code's documentation you are referenced to?

Comment: Here's the documentation and the code I do use: https://github.com/thujohn/rss-l4/pull/24 @SerhiiVasko

Comment: @ttrasn here's my addChild code: https://pastebin.com/Dc2uv7bh

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$feed->item([   
    'title' => $post->title,
    'description|cdata' => $feedy . $post->description,
    'link' => URL::to($post->slug),
    'pubDate' => $pubDate,
    'guid' => $post->title,
    'media:text' => $post->title,
    'dc:creator' => 'Μιχάλης Γεωργίου',
    'enclosure' => [
        'url'=> $image_url,
        'type' => mime_content_type($image_path),
        'length' => filesize($image_path),
    ]
]);
```